# sqlite3_open_v2 flags in delphi

Tags: delphi, sqlite

i just study in programming (Delphi).
Today i buld Sqlite3.dll (sqlcipher 3.2.0 based on sqlite 3.8.6) with MinGW.

Now i try make procedure:

```
sqlite3_open_v2(dbname,dbhandle,flags,vfx);
```

i want open connection in read\write mode with nomutex.

in documentation i see:

> The sqlite3_open_v2() interface works like sqlite3_open() except that it accepts two additional parameters for additional control over the new database connection. The flags parameter to sqlite3_open_v2() can take one of the following three values, optionally combined with the SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX, SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX, SQLITE_OPEN_SHAREDCACHE, SQLITE_OPEN_PRIVATECACHE, and/or SQLITE_OPEN_URI flags:
>
> SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY
>   The database is opened in read-only mode. If the database does not already exist, an error is returned.
>   SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE
>   The database is opened for reading and writing if possible, or reading only if the file is write protected by the operating system. In either case the database must already exist, otherwise an error is returned.
>
> SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE        0x00000002
>   SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX          0x00008000

Why this construction dont work (cant open db):

```
sqlite3_open_v2(dbname,dbhandle,$00000002 and $00008000 ,nil);
```

But this construction work:

```
sqlite3_open_v2(dbname,dbhandle,$00000002 or $00008000 ,nil);
```

Can i add two flags 00000002+00008000=00008002?

Comment: Why ? Because `$00000002 and $00008000` gives you 0 and as the help says *If the 3rd parameter to sqlite3_open_v2() is not one of the combinations shown above (open flags listed there), optionally combined with other SQLITE_OPEN_** *bits then the behavior is undefined*, you got undefined behavior. `or` is the right operator here. P.S. define constants for those flags to avoid using magical numbers.

Comment: In binary `1100 OR 1010 = 1110`, so in a sense it is the 'addition' you are looking for.  Would you like more help as to why?

Comment: I recommend that you read rob's answer at the dupe Q. And also start declaring constants so you don't have to use opaque numbers in the code.